# Android: Dialog Fragment and DatePicker Fragment incompatible types

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a `DatePicker Fragment` that appears every time I click on an `Button`. But I'm getting "Incompatible Types":

```
public class InserirActivity extends BaseActivity implements BaseActivity.OnInfoChangedListener{
(...)    
public void clicando (View v){

            DialogFragment newFragment;
            newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();  
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
```

The problem is in `newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();` because I'm getting the error `"Incompatible Types"`.
This activity extends to BaseActivity because of a callback with another Fragment.

This is my `DatePickerFragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        Log.d("DatePicker","Here!");

    }
}
```

And the `layout.xml` where I call the procedure `clicando()`:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
    android:onClick="clickando"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons_1"
    android:textColor="@color/green7"/>
```

I've already read lots of similar questions/solutions here nevertheless I can't find one for me. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking everything I noticed I had

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
=> Worked out for me

If it doesn't work then you can remove the import statements related to DialogFragment and let the IDE add the import statements relevant for it to run.

Hope it helps :)